# Help For The Copy & Paste Generation Of Coders

Tags: php

I myself am one of these types of coders, who never learned coding in a formal setting, but am instead, self-taught by the use of copy and paste scripts, and pre-authored works available through GPL projects and premium software's(which is often the way commerical script companies show you how to change, or update code in their script ie. "Copy & paste this on line 234, etc..")... this are my beginnings.

I don't understand how what I do works, but I am getting good at what I do with code, though I feel because of my informal learning methods, that I lack in knowledge, some of the really simple, but necessary principles of web coding in general(the ins and outs of servers, browsers, etc). I feel as though I have started from the inside of understanding code, the practical side.. and lack the basic fundamentals, and theorized understanding of what I am doing.

I also know quite a few others who are the same, who started learning in the same communities as I, and are pretty much at the same point as me... Feeling as though something big is missing from the picture.
I see the lacking in my discipline when I attempt to use PHP authoring tools, which I find very challenging to understand... and this is becoming a downfall on the time frames in which I complete my projects(having to hand code everything). I also find it difficult to ask for help at times, for lack of the specific language that comes with programming, and being able to use the right words to explain the intricacy of my problem.

I was a hairdresser by trade, I worked as a bartender, and hotel manager, I'm a business consultant by profession. I've been learning web development slowly now for 3 years, and I have taken on quite a few commercial projects over the past 2 years, but I'm obviously feeling some lacking in my skills & overall knowledge.

Basically, Id like to ask any experienced coders who've had similar beginnings to give me an idea on how I can adapt my coding disciplines to be more effective and productive. What would someone with such an informal understanding of programming want to seek to learn, and understand. What are the things I must know as a programmer... and what is a basic overview of the whole picture???? Feel free to direct me to articles

Any help is always appreciated.

Lea

**Edit:** Just to give a round up of my actual capabilities. I am a programmer, I do author my own code from scratch.. and sell my work. I can write PHP functions, and classes, use mysql, have a good working understanding of html & css, and am very good in the design aspects(web graphics), and am learning javascript/ajax/jquery, as I am using jquery in most of my projects. Thanks for all of the answers so far!

Comment: Similar Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743099/is-it-wise-to-use-code-copied-from-the-web-in-our-own-applications

Comment: You could try the Java tutorial to see what phrases you might learn concerning OOP. Then check MDN javascript to see that JavaScript is not class based but prototype based. Now you would know things like strongly typed, abstraction and other cool phrases I usually have to look up before fully understanding them. If you're not tired yet then I'd advice reading something on patterns, good patterns are usually lacking in PHP projects and make it hard to scale or extend. And try using PHPUnit to do unit tests on your project.

Comment: I have learned by doing most of the time as well and find that the theory mentioned above is what I was missing. Instead of reading documentation I do a var_dump or check out the variables in firebug. If it works it works and if it doesn't I have to spend the time learning the theory of it all. Now that I don't take on many projects there is time for all the reading and it helps me apply most of the knowledge to practical problems I used to encounter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We all learn differently, so don't feel handicapped because of the way you've entered the field.

I guess the simplest, easiest thing I can suggest would be to get yourself a PHP book (seeing as that's what you're familiar with right now) and start from there to build up confidence.

In your spare time, just create some very small basic apps to practice without any pressure. Then take on a language like Python, Java or .NET.. depending on what takes your fancy. With a language or two under your belt, then you can take on books like Code Complete, which will cover some of the more esoteric areas of software development.

Good luck, this is a profession where you really never stop learning.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the way to go... Ive never read a book on programming before, so I proberly feel slightly alienated by that. I find your answer very encouraging. Thanks alot:)

Answer (score 7):

- Realise that "copy and paste programming" is not actually programming, despite the name.  The act of "programming" is figuring out how something should work, and what code is needed to make that work.  Therefore, when you copy and paste some code, it is someone else who did the programming.  This isn't a bad thing necessarily, as you shouldn't always need to write code yourself.  But to call yourself a programmer, you do need to have written the code yourself.
- You will want to start humble.  Don't try to write a large complex application as your first step into programming.  There is a good reason why most people who are taught programming are first taught how to print "Hello, world".  This is because there is a lot more that you will need to know than just what code to use - you need to know where code execution starts and how it flows, and that sort of thing.  You need to be able to look at the code and step through it mentally, knowing where program execution will go next, so you understand how it will work.
- Take a tutorial or course in programming.  There is so much free stuff online.  Do not trust any tutorial that just gives you large chunks of code, make sure it forces you to actually come up with some code yourself.  Do exercises such as sorting strings, calculating fibonacci sequences, and the like, and "echo" or "print" the results.  Learn about conditional statements (like "if") and the "for" loop and play with these to do various things.
- GUI or forms programming is more complicated; make sure you know the fundamentals of the language before you go looking through any API or framework documentation to see what the language can do.  You'll need to know how execution flows, how to write functions, what types of variables you can use etc before you can effectively use an API or framework anyway.  It is boring not being able to do cool graphics or forms and sticking to basic text or number processing, but you have to walk before running.  Make sure you are doing, not just reading.  When you learn about something new like the Array type, the "while" statement, try it out.  By actually doing it, you'll "get it" a lot faster than just reading a book or website and you may be more likely to remember it.
- Read books about programming.  Some people say you should learn C before you learn anything else.  I don't necessarily agree, but if you do learn C then the book to read is "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie.  Many programming books are very interesting but either not suitable for beginners, or aren't going to teach you how to actually begin programming.  This one is an exception.
- Use a decent text editor with syntax highlighting and line numbering.  That's all you should need.  A big IDE that also does code completion and the like is not necessarily helpful at the learning stage.  Don't spend too long choosing one or setting it up.  If you don't already have one, just get Notepad++ (if you're on Windows) and be done with it.  If you don't like it you can change it once you get more proficient.  Or if you've already paid for Microsoft Visual Studio then use that, but don't go out and get it just for the sake of learning a language.  Avoid falling into the trap of spending all your time sharpening your tools and no time using them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though as I said in my question, I have completed quite a few commercial projects. So much of what your speaking about here, I can already do. I am not a complete novice, and I do author my own code. I am refering to C&P as the first methods in which I came to learn, to give everyone an idea of my beginnings. If you have a look at my other questions, you will get a better idea of my level of knowledge. Thanks again.

Comment: I think the first program I was taught in any kind of formal way was a 'guess the number' type game.  The hello world is really more of a chalk-board example, or at very least, a way to show experienced programmers about what a new language looks like.

Comment: @Lea I see.  I guess, apart from continuing to read programming books and staying in touch with programming websites (like this one), as someone who already has some decent self-taught programming skills you could try to extend your skills in other areas like marketing and particularly self-promotion, which can be important and could set you apart from other programmers.  Also you could try learning a different language.  Try Python, or Javascript.  I found I enjoyed doing that.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest and fastest way to do this? **Find a mentor**, or a set of mentors. Not necessarily a real-life mentor, they can be offline, although a real-life mentor is more practical.

You can find these people when you participate in local software development communities, e.g., forums, or user group meetings. Frequent these places, both offline and online; the amount of knowledge that you will learn is immense, not to mention the benefit of being able to bounce ideas off of other people.

[Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) and [Pragmatic Programmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161622X) are likewise excellent book suggestions above. I suggest you go with Code Complete first, as it tackles on how to make your code sensible and elegant, which you certainly can use immediately.

Goodluck!

Comment: Good suggestion about finding a mentor.  It would be particularly good for someone who has taught themselves.

Answer (score 3):

in case you're interested to becoming a better programmer, i must recommend that you read the [pragmatic programmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161622X), don't worry, it's not a full text of codes which will make you pull your hair out but useful lessons which can only be distilled from years of programming experience written in an easy to read but still very informative kind of way :)

Comment: Thanks so much for the reference, I just read the first few pages, and I'm feeling better already. This is a must on my list. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at all convinced that the premise of the "Copy & Paste Generation" is any kind of new phenomenon.  Only the tools are available to a wider audience now than before.

If you want to really hone your skills, it might be worthwhile to take some classes, either at a local community college or in a self-directed learning environment through the use of some of the [many](http://www.diveintopython.net/), [fine](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) online resources or [books](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont mean to make it sound like some new phenomenon, but alot of people will identify with what I am refering to... Which is more directed at the methods in which I, and others have learned. Thanks for your tips:)

Answer (score 1):

I believe Code Complete is another book along the same lines of the Pragmatic Programmer that has already been recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I have been your situation before, senior year of high school in an internship I "learned" c and shell programming mostly via copy and paste, and later on at various times when I may have been in a similar situation with specific technologies.

My recommendations:

1. Take a class at your CC. The one you want is the one that is the prerequisite for the advanced programming classes. They probably also offer a "I've never touched a computer before" level class but this one won't be the formal prereq for the follow on classes. This will probably be in Java.
2. Work your way through one of the better programming books that includes exercises. Kernighan and Ritchie's C Programming Language is a classic. This would be my recommendation because C is similar enough to PHP to be familiar, but different enough that you will be able to keep them separate. I say this even though you will probably never write a single line of production C. Paul Graham's ANSI Common Lisp is also a suitable choice.
3. If you are really hard core and have the dedication, you can try Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs, by Abelson and Sussman. This is the book used in the first programming course at UC Berkeley ( http://webcast.berkeley.edu/course_details.php?seriesid=1906978389 ) and at MIT ( http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-001Spring-2005/CourseHome/ ). This may be too difficult to attempt outside a school environment. It's designed for bright young students with nothing to do but study and with the regular opportunity to get tutoring from grad students. I include it only for completeness.

I would avoid any web programming books. You already know web programming. I get the impression that you are feeling like you are hitting a bit of a wall, and looking at a way around or over that wall, rather than trying to go directly through it.

I would advise against looking into any web oriented book because it will not give you the big picture, it will describe technique only as they apply to web programming. The important things to understand are how a computer actually operates, the difference between the stack and the heap, pointers, the basics of garbage collection, recursion, and it'd probably be helpful to understand at least extension mechanism. I mean, if you understand shared libraries on Unix, or DLLs on Windows, or classpath and jars on Java, or how to create a library in PHP, Ruby, Perl or Python, any one of those will be fine. It's just the concept of loading outside code that's important.

Comment: I really like your wholistic view. Its what I would've much prefered to start off with, understanding the actual PC. I agree with you, anyone with this kind of understanding will be able to approach web coding with a huge advantage knowing the "bigger picture". Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [The Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/) and see if you think it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste programming refers to using the same code several places instead of putting it in a function or class. If all you do is modify existing source code while following a howto guide, what you do is not called programming, just copy and paste.

What you need to do is read a book on programming, whatever you feel your level is. If you feel its copy and paste level, you should start with a beginners book. Forget everything you think you know, read and follow the book. When you've finished you can remember some of the clever code(?) you noticed during your C&P days.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry i didnt explain properly what I mean, but I am refering more to the methods in which i was introduced to programming. And that was through copying & pasting... I built my first script using snippets, and often used tutorial snippets. Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 0):

Mastering any skill takes time, but if you keep at it you'll become better. There is nothing inherently different about programming in that sense. Exactly how you learn best, is a highly individual matter, so it's really hard to give any meaningful advice on that. In my experience, combining different types of learning (practical experience, being around other programmers, reading books, formal education etc. etc.) in even-sized doses works better than just pursuing one type of learning (Such as formal education).

You might find these readings interesting, if you don't know them already:

- http://www.norvig.com/21-days.html
- http://softwarecraftsmanship.oreilly.com/wiki